# Moving SSIS Packages to New Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssis, migration

I have a number of SSIS packages in a number of folders on MSDB SSIS on SQL Server 2008R2.
We are migrating to a new server host but remaining on SQL Server 2008R2.

How can I copy/migrate these SSIS packages to the new server? Is Dtutil the best option?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, DTutil is still going to be the best option. I have a post, [SSIS Package Extract from MSDB](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2011/11/ssis-package-extract-from-msdb.html) on how to use dtutil + the data in the packages table to generate the call(s) to export to disk. Instead of the `file` destination, you would substitute sourceserver. If you've used folders to organize your packages, then you'll need to create them beforehand.

Script posted here for posterity. This applies for 2008+ packages or 2012/2014 package that have used the package deployment model. With 2005, `sysssispackagefolder` would be replaced with `sysdtspackages90` and `sysssispackagefolders` with `sysdtspackagefolders90`

```
;
WITH FOLDERS AS
(
    -- Capture root node
    SELECT
        cast(PF.foldername AS varchar(max)) AS FolderPath
    ,   PF.folderid
    ,   PF.parentfolderid
    ,   PF.foldername
    FROM
        msdb.dbo.sysssispackagefolders PF
    WHERE
        PF.parentfolderid IS NULL

    -- build recursive hierarchy
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        cast(F.FolderPath + '\' + PF.foldername AS varchar(max)) AS FolderPath
    ,   PF.folderid
    ,   PF.parentfolderid
    ,   PF.foldername
    FROM
        msdb.dbo.sysssispackagefolders PF
        INNER JOIN
            FOLDERS F
            ON F.folderid = PF.parentfolderid
)
,   PACKAGES AS
(
    -- pull information about stored SSIS packages
    SELECT
        P.name AS PackageName
    ,   P.id AS PackageId
    ,   P.description as PackageDescription
    ,   P.folderid
    ,   P.packageFormat
    ,   P.packageType
    ,   P.vermajor
    ,   P.verminor
    ,   P.verbuild
    ,   suser_sname(P.ownersid) AS ownername
    FROM
        msdb.dbo.sysssispackages P
)
SELECT 
    -- assumes default instance and localhost
    -- use serverproperty('servername') and serverproperty('instancename') 
    -- if you need to really make this generic
    -- File extraction command line
    'dtutil /sourceserver localhost /SQL "'+ F.FolderPath + '\' + P.PackageName + '" /copy file;".\' + P.PackageName +'.dtsx"' AS cmd
    -- Move Package command line
    -- 'dtutil /SQL "'+ F.FolderPath + '\' + P.PackageName + '" /SOURCEUSER srcUserName /SOURCEPASSWORD $Hj45jhd@X /DestServer <servername> /MOVE SQL;"'+ F.FolderPath + '\' + P.PackageName + '" /DESTUSER destUserName /DESTPASSWORD !38dsFH@v' AS cmd
FROM 
    FOLDERS F
    INNER JOIN
        PACKAGES P
        ON P.folderid = F.folderid
 WHERE
     F.FolderPath <> '\Data Collector'
```

Comment: I can just backup and restore MSDB database to new server? That will move SSIS packages?

Comment: It would. It would also copy your SQL Agent information, send mail configuration and a host of other things that you may or may not want ported.